# Is it possible to specify variable name by appending part of NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Say I have thousands of coordinates. Assume searchBarText is a NSString. Here are 3:

```
if([searchBarText isEqual:@"1000"])
    {
        self.mapView.centerCoordinate = coordinate1000;
        [self.mapView selectAnnotation:point1000 animated:YES];
    }


    else if([searchBarText isEqual:@"1002"])
    {
        self.mapView.centerCoordinate = coordinate1002;
        [self.mapView selectAnnotation:point1002 animated:YES];
    }


    else if([searchBarText isEqual:@"1005"])
    {
        self.mapView.centerCoordinate = coordinate1005;
        [self.mapView selectAnnotation:point1005 animated:YES];
    }
```

Is it possible to somehow condense this very repetitive code into something like:

```
self.mapView.centerCoordinate = coordinate(searchBarText);
[self.mapView selectAnnotation:point(searchBarText) animated:YES];
```

Comment: Investigate the use of arrays or dictionaries

Comment: I would like to know if something like this can be done.

Comment: Yes, through the use of an NSDictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's a way that should work

```
//@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *coordinate1000;
_coordinate1000 = @"it's Working!";
    NSLog(@"Magic is : %@",[self valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"coordinate%i",1000]]);
```

**Caveat**: 
this is not recommended solution to your problem, for your specific problem use Array/Dictionary as other answer mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can store it in a NSMutableDictionary where the key can be your variable name and value can be your coordinates.
While you can have a generic name for your Mutable dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

Make This method

```
-(NSString*) coordinate:(NSString*) searchBarText
{
return [@"coordinate" stringByAppendingString:searchBarText]
}
```

And use this

```
self.mapView.centerCoordinate = [self coordinate:searchBarText];
[self.mapView selectAnnotation:[self coordinate:searchBarText] animated:YES];
```

Comment: How would this access a variable of name `coordinate1000` for input 1000?

Comment: you can store values into dictionary taking key name of these variables.

Comment: Right, which is what my comment and the other answer suggested. This answer shows how to concatenate a string, but it doesn't replicate the functionality in the question. Additionally, your second block of code wouldn't compile.